# python is not accessible from powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting below error when i tried to access the installed python from powershell command prompt on windows machine.

I installed python from .exe  file which i downloaded from portal, and also while installing i checked for  environmental variable set option at start.

python is installed on my system at "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 " at this location

can anyone help where i went wrong.

Error: when i typed python from system folder

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Error : 
when i typed python from python installed location

```
PS C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32> .\python
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = ''
  sys.base_exec_prefix = ''
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python.exe'
  sys.prefix = ''
  sys.exec_prefix = ''
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
    '.\\DLLs',
    '.\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x000034d8 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Comment: You may be missing the PATH entry. See https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you set it in the Environment Variables?

Look it up here

[Set python Environment Variables in your computer](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/)